# Draw a convex hull on subset in python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, convex-hull

I am stuck on a problem regarding convex hulls.

My goal is to get a convex hull on a subset of my data.

let's say I have a dataframe consisting of 3 columns.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 0.75], 'col2': [3, 4, 2.5, 3, 2.75, 3.25, 4.25], 'col3:': [1,1,0,1,0,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If I wanted to draw a convex hull around the datapoints from col1 and col2, I would do that easily with scipy:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html

```
points = df[['col1', 'col2']].to_numpy()
hull = ConvexHull(points)

plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'k-')
    
plt.plot(points[hull.vertices,0], points[hull.vertices,1], 'r--', lw=2)
plt.plot(points[hull.vertices[0],0], points[hull.vertices[0],1], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

and the result would be the following:
[image]

all good and well, but what I want to do is include the third column of the dataframe as a condition, meaning, I would like to draw the hull only around datapoints where col3 = 1.
I am aware that for this artificial dataframe this would not make much sense, but for my real data this would work fine.

Does someone know how this would be possible?
It's probably not hard but I'm a bit stuck here.

Thank you and BR

Comment: `points = df[['col1', 'col2']].loc[df.col3.eq(1)].to_numpy()`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this is not quite what I'm looking for, since I still want to plot the entire dataset, I just want to draw the hull ONLY around those datapoints which fullfill the condition of col3=1

Comment: Just add `plt.plot(df.col1, df.col2, 'o')`